# Question regarding $\mathbb R$-automorphisms of the extension $\mathbb C:\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

[image]

How come the author makes the assertion that
$$(\alpha(i))^2=\alpha(i^2)?$$

I understand that $j=\alpha(i)$ *must be imaginary*, since it can't map to a real number or else the $\mathbb R$-automorphism won't be injective, hence, well, no longer an automorphism.

But why can't perhaps $\alpha(i)=2i$?

I can't tell why $\alpha(x+yi)=x+2yi$ isn't considered an automorphism given how it's a bijection $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ and we still have
$$(\forall k \in \mathbb R): \quad \alpha(k)=k.$$

Comment: If you had identified the book in which you found the material you are asking about, I feel sure it would make it easier to be sure it is discussing *field* automorphisms rather than *set* automorphisms.  The whole subject of *Galois groups* of field extensions is predicated on the notion of field automorphisms.

Comment: @hardmath Ahahahaha my mistake! The book is Stewart's *Galois Theory*, really shouldn't have tripped over something so small. I started this book after learning abstract algebra from Aluffi who would always pinpoint which automorphisms by explicitly saying things like $$\text{Aut}_\mathsf{Ring}(\mathbb C)$$ for the ring automorphisms of $\mathbb C$. Perhaps I just need to get used to not having everything explicitly stated for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *field* automorphism $f\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ not only satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, but also
$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. For $x=y=i$ we obtain $(f(i))^2=f(i^2)=f(-1)=-1$. The last equality follows because $f$ fixes real numbers, since it is an $\mathbb{R}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you! I had accidentally thought it was a set automorphism :)